# Need help for calculation of this capacitive power supply

Tags: power-supply, capacitive

Look at this circuit. It's an almost complete capacitive power supply with necessary part.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzgh0O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have trouble calculating:

- the input capacitor (whose reactance does the main job reducing input 220v AC voltage)(C1)
- the input resistor (I am not sure why they put this. but I think it's because the smoothing capacitor needs a lot of current to charge at first. the resistor lets it charge slowly and not take a lot of current.)(R1)
- the series resistor before the zener diode (I think it act a a current limit)(R3)
- and finally the capacity of smoothing capacitor.(C2

The values "X" mean they are given. And "?" means I don't know.

Let output voltage "V<sub>out</sub>" and output current "I<sub>out</sub>". Also the zener diode breakdown voltage "V<sub>zener</sub>" and the capacity of C2 "C<sub>smooth</sub>"
and the "C<sub>in</sub>" is the input capacitor capacity and "R<sub>in</sub>" is the input resistor resistance.

The R2 is the discharge resistor for C1 and discharges it when input AC voltage is removed.

please give me a way using formulas to calculate those parameters I mentioned while the values: V<sub>out</sub>, I<sub>out</sub>, V<sub>zener</sub> are given.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @Andyaka I could calculate C _in_ by omitting V _out_ from 220V and dividing it by I _out_ which give the reactance of C _in_. so the capacity can be calculated by solving the X _c_ =1/(2.pi.f.C) equation. but I couldn't do more so I asked this question as here are people who can probably help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the capacitive reactancelike in the previous comment, then you will get your Average current thats available .Allow something for the Zener AND allow for low mains.You can neglect the output volts and R1 the surge limiting resistor for your rough calc .Remember that analog parts like caps have tolerances so there is only acedemic purpose in doing a calc better than 5% .If you are close to 50mA per microfarad then you are OK. NOW R1 must be fitted to protect C2 and BR1 and R3 can be Zero if you get your surge limit OK .If you are running a 1 watt thruhole Zener and a 470microfarad phillips 037 series cap then 100 ohm is fine . Be VERY careful of thev surge power rating of R1 .I have seen a few Christchurch Design Engineers muck these up with resistors failing open circuit .Some resistor manufacturers like melf are good at stating surge ratings .If you have bought your resistors off a strange man then play safe by using a higher value .Dont go too low in R1 even if your parts can hack it because these days the mains volts has more harmonics than yesteryear.

Comment: I couldn't get the part "Allow something for the Zener AND allow for low mains.You can neglect the output volts and R1 the surge limiting resistor for your rough calc". Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Sorry blue Sky .Allowing something for the zener is a very old term used by one of the people who helped me when i was a child .It means that you must add some current to your calc so the zener always has a minimum current going through it even when your load current draw is maximum.Now allowing for low mains is easy .All you do here is add 15% to your calculated cap value for a 15% reduction in mains .What I did in the day was V mains =230V and V mains min =194V .Your values are likely to be different.